# Angular8 ngFor array inside array

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

This is my array which have property message which have another array.

```
chat = [{id:1, toUser:10, fromUser:11, seen:null, name:'Filip', messages:[{message:'Hello'},{message:'Hello again'}]}];
```

This is my HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let c of chat">
<h1>{{c.name}}</h1> //this works fine
<p>{{c.messages.message}}</p> //There I cant get anything. If I set c.messages[0].message I only get first result
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a second nested `ngFor`. Something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let c of chat">
  <h1>{{c.name}}</h1>
  <p *ngFor="let item of c.messages">{{item.message}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: A good developer will check if c.messages is not null or undefined. you can use `ng-container` for that.